# Laravel add query results via append in model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to append a specific column in my model which is `returns_count` it is based from a query. But when I executed it it gives me the wrong result. It has the same value from all of the results. Can someone help me with this. I think I almost got it. Thanks

Model

```
   protected $appends = [
        'returns_count'
    ];
    public function getReturnsCountAttribute(){
        $users = DB::table('users_mws')
            ->select('users_mws.*')
            ->join('users','users.id','=','users_mws.user_id')
            ->where('users.status','<>','Dumped2')
            ->orderBy('users_mws.mws_name','asc')
            ->get();
        $clientCount = array();
        foreach ($users as $data){
            $returnCount = AdminMwsReturnsEligiblesData::where('users_mws_id', $data->id)->count();
            $clientCount[] = $returnCount;
            return $clientCount;
        }
    }
```

Result (it must be different per result) i got `191` per result which is not correct

```
 {
    "id": 153,
    "user_id": 216,
    "mws_name": "1 Body",
    "oem_alias": null,
    "oem_mws_id": null,
    "user_type": "user",
    "returns_count": [
      191
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 145,
    "user_id": 211,
    "mws_name": "Activewear",
    "oem_alias": null,
    "oem_mws_id": null,
    "user_type": "user",
    "returns_count": [
      191
    ]
  },
```

The count result in this query

```
  $clientCount = array();
        foreach ($usersMws as $data){
            $returnCount = AdminMwsReturnsEligiblesData::where('users_mws_id', $data->id)->count();
            $clientCount[] = $returnCount;
            
        }
        dd($clientCount);
```

```
  0 => 191
  1 => 16
  2 => 6
  3 => 3
  4 => 25
  5 => 4
  6 => 35
  7 => 0
  8 => 115
  9 => 1
  10 => 18
  11 => 68
  12 => 14
  13 => 0
  14 => 36
  15 => 32
  16 => 147
  17 => 8
 ...
```

Comment: The `return $clientCount;` looks incorrect and would probably stop after the first loop.

Comment: i see sir @NigelRen but when i put it outside the loop it wont run anymore it throws an maximum 60 secs execution time. What do i need to do?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: its `"laravel/framework": "^6.0",` sir @Rwd

Comment: As Nigel Ren mentioned above, move the `return` statement so that it is below the `foreach` loop.

Comment: i tried it sir but it takes too long and i think its wrong also i got maximum 60 secs execution time. @Rwd

Comment: The way you're going about things does look really inefficient, you should always try to avoid queries in loops where possible. What "model" is the code above actually inside i.e. what table is it associated with?

Comment: it uses 2 tables sir. can we continue in chat sir? i really need help in this one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228192/discussion-between-rwd-and-vince).

Comment: What is the name of the model? and what is the table name of the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get attribute data, avoid using for loop. it may cause lag.

try this code. i separate the query into the scope. and appends must be direct.

```
protected $appends = [
        'returns_count'
    ];

 public function getReturnsCountAttribute(){
        return AdminMwsReturnsEligiblesData::where('users_mws_id', $this->id)->count();
    }
```

Scoped:

```
public function scopeReturnCount($query)
    {
        $query->select('users_mws.*')->join(
            'users',
            'users_mws.user_id',
            '=',
            'users.id'
        )
        ->where('users.status','<>','Dumped2')
        ->orderBy('users_mws.mws_name','asc');

        return $query;
    }
```

Controller:

```
$users = UsersMws::returnCount()->get();
```

Model scoped function can also carry the appends data.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. Also this one is working. Thanks again